# Fixed vs rolling forecasts: Empirical evidence

Tags: forecasting, references, moving-window

Many sources online recommend that we use a rolling window to make forecasts. As I am in a choice between using a fixed window and a rolling window for my data I am trying to find any empirical evidence to get a sense of the improvement in forecast accuracy provided by using a rolling window. However, I have a really hard time finding any such evidence. Most sources seems to rely heavily on intuition and the "fact" that not considering too old observations "should" lead to better accuracy than using a simple split with a training and a test set that uses all available data.

So my question is, do you know of any empirical evidence that compares a simple split window forecasting to a rolling window forecasting?

To be clear, with fixed I mean that if I have data from 2000 to 2020, I use all the data from 2000 to 2016 as a training set and then 2017-2020 as a test set to evaluate my out-of-sample forecasts.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume your goal is to choose or parameterize a forecasting method based on forecast accuracy on a holdout sample, right? The recommendation of using a rolling window has more to do with the fact that evaluating a single forecast will yield more variability in the outcome than aggregating the accuracies over multiple rolling windows. No, I don't know of published research in this direction, though it would be easy to run an analysis on a published dataset, like the M competition data.

Comment: Thanks for your input, Stephan. Yes, you are correct regarding my goal. I am also familiar with your point about variability. However, I am just not convinced, yet, that the difference between fixed and rolling is so easy to evaluate. How can we infer that aggregating over multiple rolling forecasts, of which all uses only a small subset of the data as burn-in period, is definitely superior to using a maximal burn-in period? I mean, dont we have a trade-off here between many small vs one large window instead of the trade-off between only one vs multiple forecasts?

Comment: You will still say that we can compare different models easier using rolling windows, because a single forecast may be more affected by chance even though we use a larger window. But then, how likely is it that a model which yields a better forecast using all the data, will perform worse on a smaller subset or just another subset? And where is the "cut" in this trade off? That is, which is the optimal window to use for a rolling method? Obviously, only one season/cycle should not be enough (12 periods/months if data is yearly). So is 36 months a preferred window? The goal then must be to...

Comment: ...increase the window such that it becomes large enough to catch all seasonality but small enough to get enough forecasts to use for accuracy testing.

Comment: While I am not aware of any empirical studies on this area - the choice as to whether to use a fixed or a rolling window depends significantly on the data being analysed. For instance, use of a fixed window to analyse temperature data would not make much sense from an accuracy standpoint, as a fixed moving average that is being used to forecast winter temperatures would not be as accurate given that summer temperatures would also be included in the average. On the other hand, if one is analysing a series without significant seasonality - then a fixed moving average may be a better choice.

Comment: I have seen some work in the past and rolling performs better for general purpose forecasting. One setup that did surprisingly well is a test split of the last n and then reversing your series and creating a test split from that as well. As others have pointed out everything depends on data, for my purposes I trained up an RL agent that is fed time series characteristics and recommends the testing strategy and test sizes. Does pretty well in testing but most importantly saves a ton of computation time not doing 3 rounds of fit/predicting for every series. Don't recommend but it is interesting!

Comment: Thanks guys for your input. @Tylerr would it be possible for you to find any of the work in the past that you mention?

Comment: I do get the impression from trying to entering the field of forecasting that the empirical grounding is not waterproof. This is confirmed, sort of, by Bergmeir et al. here: https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.10716 They write that...

Comment: "Thus, there is no generally accepted standard for forecast eval-
uation in every possible scenario. This gap has harmed the evaluation practices used
along with ML methods for forecasting significantly in the past. It is damaging the
area currently, with spurious results in many papers, with researchers new to the field
not being able to distinguish between methods that work and methods that don’t, and
the associated waste of resources."